# Event on multiple google charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a problem, when using the select event for google charts, it only uses one chart for the event (the last chart in the for loop). Is there a way to bind the same event on multiple charts?

This is my code:
You can see I add a select listener for each pie chart but only the last pie(on page) alerts something.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>
    <?php

    class typeChart {

        public $type;
        public $function;
        public $addit;
        public $title;
        public $jscript;

        public function __construct($type, $string, $title, $additional = 0) {
            $this->type = $type;
            $this->function = "report/" . $string;
            $this->addit = $additional;
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->jscript = $string;
        }

    }

    $arr = array();

    array_push($arr, new typeChart('table', 'getDataProjects', 'Data Projects'));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getStatusProjects', 'Status Projects', 1));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getTypeProjects', 'Type Projects', 1));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getBillingProjects', 'Billing Projects', 1));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getTypeFinance', 'Type Finance'));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getTypeInterventions', 'Type Interventions'));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('bar', 'getCompletedYear', 'Completed Year'));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getLeadTimeProjects', 'LeadTime Projects'));
    array_push($arr, new typeChart('pie', 'getDeadlineInvoicing', 'Deadline Invoicing'));
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart,table"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
<?php
$counter = 0;
?>
<?php foreach ($arr as $res) { ?>
    <?php
    $counter++;
    $datatable = 'dataTable' . $counter;
    ?>

                function selectHandler(myChart) {
                    var selectedItem = myChart.getSelection()[0];
                    if (selectedItem) {
                        var topping = <?php echo $datatable; ?>.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                        alert(topping);
                    }
                }

                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url($res->function); ?>",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;




                var <?php echo $datatable; ?> = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

                var options = {
                    title: '<?php echo $res->title; ?>'

                };



                $("#charts").append('<table>');
    <?php if ($res->type == 'table') { ?>
                    $("#charts").append('<tr><td><div id="<?php echo $res->title; ?>" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto;"></div></td></tr>');
                    var <?php echo $res->jscript; ?> = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('<?php echo $res->title; ?>'));

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>, 'select', function() {
                        selectHandler(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>);
                    });

        <?php echo $res->jscript; ?>.draw(<?php echo $datatable; ?>, options);

    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($res->type == 'pie') { ?>
                    $("#charts").append('<td><div id="<?php echo $res->title; ?>" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div></td>');
                    var <?php echo $res->jscript; ?> = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $res->title; ?>'));



                    google.visualization.events.addListener(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>, 'select', function() {
                        selectHandler(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>);
                    });

        <?php echo $res->jscript; ?>.draw(<?php echo $datatable; ?>, options);

        <?php
        if ($res->addit == 1) {
            $bar = $res->title . 'Bar';
            ?>

                        $("#charts").append('<td><div id="<?php echo $bar; ?>" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div></td></tr>');
                        var x = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $bar; ?>'));
                        x.draw(<?php echo $datatable; ?>, options);
                        google.visualization.events.addListener(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>, 'select', function() {
                            selectHandler(<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>);
                        });

        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php } ?>






    <?php } ?>



<?php } ?>

            $("#charts").append('</table>');




        }







    </script>
</head>
<body>



    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/index'); ?>"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('manage/index'); ?>"><span>MANAGE</span></a></li>
            <li class='active'><a href="<?php echo site_url('report/index'); ?>"><span>REPORT</span></a></li>
            <li style="float: right"><a href="<?php echo site_url('login/logout'); ?>"><span>LOGOUT</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <table id="charts">




    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without knowing what `<?php echo $res->jscript; ?>` outputs, I can't help you.  Open the page in a browser and paste some example javascript that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is better, but I'd really like to see what the javascript looks like when rendered by the server (ie, after PHP has run).  I suspect your problem is multi-layered, as you are declaring multiple variables with the same name (eg: every time though the loop, you create variables `jsonData`, `data`, `options`, etc, all in the same scope).  Once you've fixed that, getting the select handler to work on multiple charts will be easy.  I'll post an answer with that part below.

Answer (score 2):

Using a single event handler with multiple charts is not difficult, you just have to cheat a bit.  Given this event handler:

```
function selectHandler(myChart) {
    var selectedItem = myChart.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
        var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        alert(topping);
    }
}
```

You would need to set up your event with a custom function that calls `selectHandler` and passes in the chart:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(myChart1, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(myChart1);
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(myChart2, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(myChart2);
});
```

Your code will be a bit more complex because you not only have multiple charts, but you also have multiple DataTables (which are being overwritten in the current version of your code).  You need to fix your variable naming and then pass the DataTable along with the chart as parameters to `selectHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I edited my code and I am using now multiple datatable variable names however when I click a pie chart it says : Table has no rows ?

Comment: Update your question with the new code (preferably including the post-render javascript instead of the PHP code) so I can see what is going on.